# Issue with mails sent by Outbound Email

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are sending the mails in chunk of thousands through Outbound Email. We have a newsletter with four images embedded on it. But we have faced a problem that one of these four images getting embedded on all the places in newsletter where the other images should appear when we send mails(I mean to say same image is appearing on all the places). Preview of newsletter page is perfectly fine in CMS. Suggest solution if any.

We are sending the mails in chunk of thousands through Outbound Email. We have a newsletter with four images embedded on it. But we have faced a problem that one of these four images getting embedded on all the places in newsletter where the other images should appear when we send mails(I mean to say same image is appearing on all the places). Preview of newsletter page is perfectly fine in CMS. Suggest solution if any.

This is our code in one DWT:

```
<tr style="background:@@header_background_color@@ url(@@TrimSpacesFromString(website_url)@@/@@TrimSpacesFromString(header_background_image_url)@@) repeat-x left top;">
    <td style="width:98px; padding:4px 14px 7px">
        <a href="@@website_url@@">
            <img src="@@EmbedImage(logo)@@" width="98" height="98" border="0" alt="@@GetKeyValueForTitle('football_club','AC')@@"/>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td  style="width:453px; padding:0px 14px 7px 0; vertical-align:top;">
        another table with data
    </td>
</tr>
```

2nd DWT Code

```
<tr>
    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="list" -->        
    <td style="<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex<(listCount-1)" -->padding-right<!-- TemplateEndIf --><!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex==(listCount-1)" -->padding-left<!-- TemplateEndIf -->:7px;">
        <table style="width:285px; padding:0 0 20px 0" cellspacing="0">         
            <tr>
            <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="image" -->
                <td rowspan="2" style="padding:0px 5px 0 0px; width:127px; vertical-align:top;">                        
                    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="GetTextValueFromCompOrEmbedField(ID,'link', 'external_link','0')!=''" --> 
                        <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="GetStatusForExternalUrl(GetTextValueFromCompOrEmbedField(ID,'link','external_link','0'))" -->                    
                            <a href="@@TrimSpacesFromString(GetTextValueFromCompOrEmbedField(ID,'link','external_link','0'))@@" 
                            style="color:@@header_link_color@@; text-decoration:none;" >
                                <!-- <img src="@@EmbedImage(image)@@" width="127" height="108" border="0" alt="players" /> -->                                  
                                <img src="@@EmbedImage(image)@@" width="127" height="108" border="0" alt="@@GetKeyValueForLabel('player','CM')@@" />
                            </a>
                        <!-- TemplateEndIf -->                          
                </td>
                <!-- TemplateEndIf -->                      
            </tr>

        </table>
    </td>
    <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->      
</tr>
```

Comment: Start by posting your template code?

Comment: Which version of Tridion are you using? 
2011 GA, Hotfix Rollup 1, Service Pack 1, or Service Pack 1 Hotfix Rollup 1...

Comment: We are using EmbedImage() method for embedding the images.

Comment: We would still like to see more of the template code..

Comment: "We are using EmbedImage() method for embedding the images" doesn't really tell us any more...

Comment: Do I need to paste all the DWT's here??

Comment: You need to paste the minimum part that you've already done that is needed for someone to help you. Dumping all your code is as sure a way to turn anyone off from being willing to help you as is posting no code at all (when code is the only thing that is relevant).

Comment: With My DWT page is rendering well when I preview or even test mail myself. Issue comes when we send mail.In DWT there is no such thing where i am using same multimedia component id to EmbedImage method. this method is called from four different dwt's and CT's are also diffent for all these dwt's. they don't have any interconnection.

Comment: Can you reduce the DWT to just the minimum needed to reproduce the problem? That should not be difficult, given that it seems to be repeating the same construct over and over. But more importantly: it is something ***you*** can do before sharing the code with us, thus making it easier for everyone to help with your problem.

Comment: Somehow the variable 'image' seems to get the same value when you send the mail. Have you tried running the template in the template builder while inspecting the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a defect in earlier versions whereby sending mails multi-threaded or while the system was under heavy load could occasionally cause the image IDs of embedded images or attachments to be a string of zeros instead of a unique ID.

This was hotfixed for 2009 SP1 and incorporated into 2011 SP1 as well.

You are on an earlier version, so the recommended solution is to upgrade to SP1 HR1.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue in Tridion 2011. It's fixed in 2011 SP1. Whenever there was sending of emails in huge amount occurs then Embedding of Image was not working correctly in Tridion 2011.